# Bootstrap navbar background color not changing

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using the bootstrap navbar for my website. If I want to change the background color of the navbar I can do it using:

```
<!-- Navbar -->
<nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation" >

    <div class="container-fluid" style="background-color:#000000">

       <p>hi</p>

    </div>

</nav>
```

But if I try to use css in an external sheet using either

```
.nav_backcolor {
   background-color:#000000;
}
```

or overiding the bootstrap classes in my stylesheet using

```
.navbar-default {

background-color:#000000;

}
```

and adding the class like

```
<!-- Navbar -->
<nav class="navbar navbar-default nav_backcolor" role="navigation" >

<div class="container-fluid">

   <p>hi</p>

</div>

</nav>
```

it doesn't work. Any help please?

Comment: Something else might be interfering as that should work fine. Do you have a jsfiddle or a website link?

Comment: http://www.joshpjackson.com/home.php is the website. The code is as shown below, but still no difference.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe Bootstrap uses the background image for `linear-gradient` which was causing an issue, try just setting only the main background attribute:

```
.navbar-default {
  background: #000000;
}
```

Comment: You also have to override and remove the background image and gradient that Bootstrap already have set. You don't see the color because the image is above it.

Comment: You can do it with a `background-image: none;`.

Comment: In your layout-styles.css have you tried the `background: #000;` ?

Comment: No problem, happy to help :)

Answer (score 4):

Try adding "!important" when adding the class to your CSS like this

```
.navbar-default {
    background: #000 !important;
}
```

Comment: I thought this was bad practice?

Comment: This ended up working for me in Bootstrap 4. What I also realized is, while setting up the navbar class, Bootstrap has built-in default color schemes, therefore, putting `!important` helped override it.

Answer (score 0):

As the comments say, the html and css itself is fine.

The page you linked can't find your style sheet file. Fix the url to your css file and you should be fine.

UPDATE: Seeing that it still has problems you can remove the Bootstrap theme to make it easier for yourself. If you're gonna do a lot of styling you might be better off removing the theme entirely so that you don't have to override it for every small change.

Comment: sorry, fixed it, but still no luck